# Why when printing a vector is str(vector) implicitly called?

Tags: python, vector, printing, maya, pymel

Everything below this paragraph is from the book Practical Maya Programming. In the second to last line the author says that the `print` statement with argument `t` implicitly calls `str(t)`, I'd like to know why, also in the second block of code the author creates `vect` and assigns it to the value `xform.translate.get()`, couldn't he have just continued using `t` which is also assigned to `xform.translate.get()`?

```
>>> xform.translate
Attribute(u'pSphere1.translate')
>>> t = xform.translate.get()
>>> print t
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The translation value of the sphere transform, which is highlighted, appears to be a list. It isn't. The translation value is an instance of pymel.core.datatypes.Vector. Sometimes we need to more aggressively introspect objects. I think this is one of the few areas where PyMEL made a mistake. Calling str(t) returns a string that looks like it came from a list, instead of looking like it came from a Vector. Make sure you have the correct type. I've spent hours hunting down bugs where I was using a Vector instead of a list, or vice versa.

```
>>> vect = xform.translate.get()
>>> lst = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> str(vect)
'[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
>>> str(lst)
'[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
>>> print t, lst # The print implicitly calls str(t)
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of Python's datamodel. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

> `object.__str__(self)` Called by `str(object)` and the built-in functions
>   `format()` and `print()` to compute the “informal” or nicely printable
>   string representation of an object. The return value must be a string
>   object.
>
> This method differs from `object.__repr__()` in that there is no
>   expectation that `__str__()` return a valid Python expression: a more
>   convenient or concise representation can be used.
>
> The default implementation defined by the built-in type object calls
>   `object.__repr__()`.

So as you can see, Python's `print(object)` calls  `object.__str__()` internally which returns the string representation of your object. Calling `str(object)` also returns `object.__str__()`.

Due to that fact, both `print(object)` and `str(object)` will give you the same visual output.